# While function with string argument

Tags: python, string, while-loop

I am trying to learn Python and can't get my head around why this `while` loop I found breaks:

```
while string:
    print("Test")
    string = string[3:]
```

With for example

```
string = "123456789"
```

The output is:

```
Test
Test
Test
```

The way I understood the while function is, that it breaks only when the expression following the while command is False. But how can string = string[3:] be False, I mean it just changes string form being "123456789" to being "456789"?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Python, like JavaScript and PHP has "falsy" values. An empty-string is "falsy", for example. Your string starts off as `"123456789"`, then it's `"456789"`, then it's `"789"`, and then it's `""`, which is considered `false` and the `while` loop breaks.

Comment: If you don't understand how a program works by looking at it, grab a sheet of grid-lined paper and execute it by-hand. You don't need a computer to do computations :)

Comment: Empty strings are `Falsy`. https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/

Comment: Thank you guys very much. That makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after the first iteration, we've

```
string = 456789
```

after the second iteration

```
string = 789
```

after that when we assign
`string[3:]` (now this becomes '' **empty string**)
which is falsy value and loop exits

Comment: Thank you! I forgot that it removes parts of the string every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have put
String = string[3:]
In the iteration, every time the loop executes it will remove the first 3 digits making it
[4,5,6,7,8,9] after first iteration
Then
[7,8,9] after second iteration
And finally
[] after third iteration
Which makes it false